# How do I resize a path already closed on an HTML5 canvas?

Tags: html, path, html5-canvas, dynamic-resizing, 2d-context-api

I have a quadratic curve rendered on a canvas. I want to animate it by means of window.setInterval and changing it's dimensions (note not simply changing it's scale) thereafter.

How do I retain an editable reference to the path after calling context.closePath()?

Comment: Once you've drawn something on the `canvas` it's pixels, it doesn't retain an object representation.  If you want to manipulate objects instead of pixels either use [SVG](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-map-element.html#svg-0) or [use a library](http://kineticjs.com/)

Comment: so it's not possible to 'redraw' a path already visible on the canvas? Or is there another way like deleting the old one and putting a new one in it's place?

Comment: No, once drawn it's just pixels.  Animation in `canvas` is achieved by clearing pixels and drawing new, slightly different, pixels.

Comment: You can clear the canvas and just redraw the path with different parameters. If you have stuff you don't want to clear just put the path on it's own canvas.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend that you maintained a reference to the path in a new `Path` object; that way you could modify x, y, points etc on the fly and then render it each animation step.

```
var testPath = new Path(100, 100, [[40, 40], [80, 80]]);
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function Path(x, y, points)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.points = points;
}

function update()
{
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
    ctx.moveTo(testPath.points[0][0], testPath.points[0][1]);
    for (var i = 1; i < testPath.points.length; i++)
    {
        ctx.lineTo(testPath.points[i][0], testPath.points[i][1]);
    }
    ctx.stroke();
    testPath.points[1][1]++; // move down

    // loop
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

update();​
```

For some reason JSFiddle doesn't play nice with Paul Irish's requestAnimationFrame polyfill but it should work locally. I'd definitely recommend this over setInterval.

http://jsfiddle.net/d2sSg/1/